# What does "the first time" mean in the description of the "Spotless" hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

On the [Winter Bash 2021 homepage](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/), the short description of the "Spotless" hat is

> Write a perfect question the first time

If I click on "About this hat", the [full description](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/spotless) says

> No edits or flags on a positive, open question asked during Winter Bash for one week.

There is no reference in the full description to anything that is done "the first time". Of course, any hat can only be earned once per site, so there should be no need to specify that.

**What does "the first time" mean in the short description of the "Spotless" hat?**

Comment: sadly, it means that "nice" users can prevent you from getting the hat with a simple, unneeded edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that you get the hat if you ask a perfect question at the very first go, i.e., you or someone else does not end up editing it later on.

Comment: I see, it was simple enough. I though there might be some additional requirement.

Answer (score 5):

The first time here means it needs no editing even from your own self later. So when you ask this question it shouldn't get edited later by you or anyone else also.